# how to create array with push in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I will be select my data from MySQL then I loop this result and then I create an array with push. but I got two results after creating the array. the first array is empty and the second result is normal.

this is my code

```
app.all("/social-feed-reply", isUserAllowed, function (req, res) {
  // console.log('......here');
  // console.log(req.query);
  // console.log('.......new test');
  // console.log(req.query.id);
  var sql = "  SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_id IN(?) ";
  db.query(sql, [req.query.id, 0], function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //here  is i got normal result
    var newArrays = [];
    Object.keys(result).forEach(function (key) {
      newArrays.push(result[key].book_id);
    });
    console.log(newArrays);
    //when is console the newArrays then i got two result  exemple :[] [ 7, 5 ]
  });
});
```

how can I remove the empty array?

[image]

Comment: What API requests are you making to trigger that log?

Comment: because  you console.log before the asynchronous code in `function (err, result, fields) {` runs - edit: nevermind - your code formatting is confusing

Comment: Also, could you fix the indentation of that console.log, as written it's really hard to tell that it's inside the callback to db.query, rather than the callback to app.all

Comment: @Bravo I don't think that's right, the console.log is inside the callback to db.query, it's just hard to tell because the code is badly formatted.

Comment: Also, what is going on with `Object.keys` here? The second parameter to the callback from query (assuming you're using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) is an array.